# I need to install GRUB 2 for Windows 8.1

Tags: 64-bit, windows-8.1, grub2, ubuntu-14.04, kali-linux

I have Windows 8.1 32-bit on my PC and I want to install Kali Linux 1.0.8 64-bit or Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit on my PC (my PC can run a 64-bit OS). I need GRUB2 to install the OS to my bootloader but I can't find the page to download and install it. Is it just for Linux or can I install it on my Windows system? I have a program called WinGrub but I don't know how to use it. How can I Get GRUB2 on my system?

Comment: You do not need to get GRUB2 separately. This bootloader comes with Linux and will allow you to dual boot (give an option to select between Windows & Linux at start-up). So just install Linux, it will take care of the rest.

Comment: What do I do to dual boot?

Comment: Can I use WinGrub to Dual boot Linux?

Comment: Ok. Have you installed Linux in the first place?

Comment: No, I have Windows 8.1 32-bit.

Comment: Great. Please install Ubuntu or Kali Linux. This installation will provide you with GRUB2 boot loader.

Comment: Ok I sure will.

Comment: Request you to approve the answer below and close this question

Comment: Have you ever installed Linux systems before. Sorry if i'm rude - i just want to protect you from wiping your HDD with linux installaion.

Comment: No, but I am going to.

Comment: Please ensure that you have empty partitions to install linux. When you pass through installation screens - be careful when you select the HDD and its partitions you will select for Linux. Recently, I helped someone install Windows 7 back because he had totally wiped his Windows installation with Linux.

Comment: I have created a 19GB partition.

Comment: Click on "Custom" when you select the partition for linux installation. Create two partitions out of the 19GB space. First is "/" or "root" and next is "SWAP". How much RAM do you have? Say if it is 4 GB -then you have to create a swap partition of size 4 GB and the remaining 15 GB you can use for "/" (root) partition.

Comment: I have a 3GB's of RAM.

Comment: Then allocate 3 GB of SWAP space. This is similar to your pagefile size in Windows. Remaining 16 GB for "/" or root partition.

Comment: Should you have any question during linux installation, please post that as a question. I will be happy to help. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you install Linux, during the process of installation - GRUB boot loader will be installed to your system. This boot loader will allow you to dual boot between Windows and Linux